# Unable to set custom gas limit for Oraclize query

Tags: gas, out-of-gas, oracles

I have an Oraclize query like the following:

```
function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) onlyOraclize { 
    // do things
    update();
}

function update() payable onlyOwnerOrOraclize {

    string memory part1 = "[URL] ['json(https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke).result.random.data.0', '\\n{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"generateIntegers\",\"params\":{\"apiKey\":${[decrypt] BAKDeam1gVg++DgtVnOA3WuDkzbAaRgY4xOXmdvSQSteMyI94gNWyWcc0uDpVJtikYyzClR6Kvw5xbEswpJryBwNirC7sKsP23rQovooh1xQxBlId6cNgwb5UBzidOB0dVvl7EntjRxRZmSVBihSjpSEa7TRPjU=},\"n\":1,\"min\":0,\"max\":";

    string memory maxRandomNumber = uint2str(3);

    string memory part2 = ",\"replacement\":true,\"base\":10${[identity] \"}\"},\"id\":1${[identity] \"}\"}']";

    string query = strConcat(part1, maxRandomNumber, part2);

    bytes32 rngId = oraclize_query(60, "nested", query);

}
```

While I have a contract with plenty of Ether in it, the default gas limit for Oraclize calls (200000) isn't enough (unless I comment out `update();` in the callback so the query only runs once). Per the docs (https://docs.oraclize.it/#ethereum-quick-start-custom-gas-limit-and-gas-price) setting the gas limit should just be the 4th parameter in the `oraclize_query`. But if I try the following (to set gas at 500000):

```
bytes32 rngId = oraclize_query(60, "nested", query, 500000);
```

The query doesn't get run at all. Why would this be?

As a sidenote, without a nested query with encrypted API key, and just doing it as follows:

```
oraclize_query(60, "URL", "json(https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke).result.random.data.0", '\n{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"generateIntegers","params":{"apiKey":"my-api-key","n":1,"min":0,"max":3,"replacement":true,"base":10},"id":1}');
```

200000 gas is enough for it to run as many times as it needs as long as the contract has Ether in it. But with a nested/encrypted query it needs more gas.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your last reply, that's the possible answer, **if you haven't got any ether** on the contract yet, **it's not possible to do the query**, because `__callback` will never trigger (as Oracle knows you haven't got enough ether to pay for the query result).

Maybe another point to look at is the fact that if **you set a gas prize which is too low for the query, the response and it's corresponding `__callback` can be delayed a lot** looking like the query doesn't work.

Don't know on whitch testnet you are, but if is a PoW testnet.. The delay will be massive.

- So try to call `update()` after the constructor finnishes and you have some ether on your contract.
- Try to set a higher GasPrice in order to recieve the query results a bit earlier if you are on a PoW envoirment. By using: `oraclize_setCustomGasPrice(xxxxx);`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is I was calling `update()` in the constructor function and creating the contract without sending Ether (only adding to the contract balance after the contract had deployed). I instead called `update()` manually after deploying the contract, sending some Ether with it:

```
contractInstance.update({from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas:1000000, value: web3.toWei(0.1, "ether")})
```